# Key ordering vs. ordering of original columns with gather()

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr

Does key ordering depend on whether I first list the columns *to gather* vs. those *not to gather*?

This is my data.frame:

```
library(tidyr)
wide_df <- data.frame(c("a", "b"), c("oh", "ah"), c("bla", "ble"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
colnames(wide_df) <- c("first", "second", "third")
wide_df

 first second third
1     a     oh   bla
2     b     ah   ble
```

First I gather all columns in a specific order, and my ordering is respected in the key listing as *second, first*, although the columns are actually ordered as *first, second*:

```
long_01_df <- gather(wide_df, my_key, my_value, second, first, third)
long_01_df

  my_key my_value
1 second       oh
2 second       ah
3  first        a
4  first        b
5  third      bla
6  third      ble
```

Then I decide to exclude one column from gathering:

```
long_02_df <- gather(wide_df, my_key, my_value, second, first, -third)
long_02_df

 third my_key my_value
1   bla second       oh
2   ble second       ah
3   bla  first        a
4   ble  first        b
```

The keys are again ordered as *second, first*. Then I code it like this, believing to be doing the exact same thing:

```
long_03_df <- gather(wide_df, my_key, my_value, -third, second, first)
long_03_df
```

And I get the keys ordered according to the real column order in the original data.frame:

```
 third my_key my_value
1   bla  first        a
2   ble  first        b
3   bla second       oh
4   ble second       ah
```

This behavior does not even change, when I call the function with `factor_key = TRUE`. What I am missing?

Comment: Interesting. Seems as if the exclusions should be the tail. Applies also to `dplyr::select(iris[, 1:3], -Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, Sepal.Width)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Summary

The reason for this is that you can not mix negative and positive indices. (You also should not: it simply makes no sense.) If you do that, `gather()` will ignore some of the indices.

### Detailed answer

Also for standard indexing you are not allowed to mix positive and negative indices:

```
x <- 1:10
x[c(4, -2)]
## Error in x[c(4, -2)] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
```

It makes sense that this is the case: Indexing with `4` tells R to only keep the fourth element. There is no need to tell it explicitly to throw away the second element in addition.

According to the documentation of `gather()`, selecting columns works the same way as in dplyr's `select()`. So let's play with that. I'll work with a subset of `mtcars`:

```
mtcars <- mtcars[1:2, 1:5]
mtcars
##                mpg cyl disp  hp drat
## Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110 3.90
## Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90
```

You can use positive and negative indexing with `select()`:

```
select(mtcars, mpg, cyl)
##              mpg cyl
## Mazda RX4      21   6
## Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6

select(mtcars, -mpg, -cyl)
##               disp  hp drat
## Mazda RX4      160 110  3.9
## Mazda RX4 Wag  160 110  3.9
```

Also for `select()`, mixing positive and negative indices makes no sense. But instead of throwing an error, `select()` seems to ignore all indices that have a different sign than the first one:

```
select(mtcars, mpg, -hp, cyl)
##               mpg cyl
## Mazda RX4      21   6
## Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6

select(mtcars, -mpg, hp, -cyl)
##               disp  hp drat
## Mazda RX4      160 110  3.9
## Mazda RX4 Wag  160 110  3.9
```

As you can see, the results are exactly the same as before.

For your examples with `gather()`, you use these two lines:

```
long_02_df <- gather(wide_df, my_key, my_value, second, first, -third)
long_03_df <- gather(wide_df, my_key, my_value, -third, second, first)
```

According to what I've shown above, these lines are identical to:

```
long_02_df <- gather(wide_df, my_key, my_value, second, first)
long_03_df <- gather(wide_df, my_key, my_value, -third)
```

Note that there is nothing in the second line that would indicate your preferred ordering of the keys. It only says that `third` should be omitted.